# Move SQL Server file and the Master database file

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I move my SQL Server database `.mdf` and `.ldf` log files, alongside with the usernames and passwords? Because copy pasting the `master.mdf` is causing for the service not to start.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ALTER DATABASE with MODIFY FILE

an example would be:

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE test SET OFFLINE;
GO
-- Copy your files to the new destination
ALTER DATABASE test 
    MODIFY FILE ( NAME = test_log, 
                  FILENAME = 'C:\temp\test_ldf.ldf');
ALTER DATABASE test 
    MODIFY FILE ( NAME = test, 
                  FILENAME = 'C:\temp\test.mdf');

GO

ALTER DATABASE test SET ONLINE;
GO
```

Comment: where should I do this ? Management Studio ?

Comment: The script above is thought for Management Studio, but you also send the commands between GO with any other client connected to your SQL Server.